# How to escape dollar sign in mysql when executed by command line?

Tags: mysql

I tried to update an hash password in MySql by command line.

But I found the dollar sign make the final value wrong.

```
$ mysql -uhomestead -p'secret' foobarDB -e "UPDATE users SET 
 password='$2y$10$vmBPs',email='foobar@example.com' WHERE id = 1;"
```

The final value in password column turn out to be `y0` but not `$2y$10$vmBPs`

Can anyone give me some hint?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the dollar sign characters using a backslash:

```
$ mysql -uhomestead -p'secret' foobarDB -e "UPDATE users SET
password='\$2y\$10\$vmBPs',email='foobar@example.com' WHERE id = 1;"
```